# How can I create an empty arraylist that stores the user's input in java?

Tags: java

What I want to do is create an empty list that can store a maximum of upto 4 elements, so either 1, 2, 3, 4 or even none. It performs a check if any value given by the user has been entered more than once, if so provides an error message. I also need then those values to be printed out using system.out.println();

I have created an empty list

```
ArrayList<Class> myArray= new ArrayList<Class>();
```

but I am not sure how many elements it can contain, I want it to contain upto 4, but none at the start, only start storing once the user gives a value.

lets say, I ask the user the following questions and they answer them.

How many legs does a dog have? 4
How many eyes does a dog have? 2
How many nose does a dog has? 1

I want that to be stored in the array list, and then lets say the user wants choose dog again, I want an error to be displayed. The answers the user gives is in numbers, can be integers or doubles.

I cannot seem to figure out how to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use an `ArrayList` for this. Create a class, instantiate it, and store the results in the object's fields.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention whether this was even possible in arraylist, btw, How would I go about using your specified route, creating an Object of a Class.

Comment: You would start by reading up on how to create classes and objects. This is what the Java tutorials are for.

Comment: [Classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have an **array** with a fixed size, *I hope this may help you* :-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int counter = 0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter your number from 1-4 : ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            if(number >= 1 && number <= 4){
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.length ; j++ ){
                    if(number == arr[j] || number == arr[j+1] || number == arr[j+2] ||number == arr[j+3] ){
                        System.out.print("Already exists ... ");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        arr[counter] = number;
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }while(number < 1 || number > 4 || counter < 4);
    }
}
```